# JAX-B handling double nested elements from xml

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

Basically im trying to unmarhall this

```
<polls xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="polls.xsd">
<poll id="1">
    <title>WSD Meeting</title>
    <state>Open</state>
    <userID>1</userID>
    <datecreated>88/88/1996</datecreated>
    <location>UTS</location>
    <description>Meeting for assignment</description>
    <meetings>
        <meeting option ='1'>
            <time>12:00</time>
            <date>99/88/1996</date>
            <responses>
                <response>John Doe</response>
            </responses>
        </meeting>
        <meeting option ='2'>
            <time>12:00</time>
            <date>99/88/1996</date>
            <responses>
                <response>John Doe</response>
                <response>John Smith</response>
            </responses>
        </meeting>
    </meetings>
</poll>
  </polls>
```

and the unmarshalling hits trouble when I get to the Meetings
this is the Poll class

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Poll implements Serializable {
@XmlAttribute
private int ID;
private String title;
private int state;
private int userID;
private String datecreated;
private String location;
private String description;
@XmlElement(name = "meetings")
private ArrayList<Meeting> meetings = new ArrayList<Meeting>();
```

and this is the meeting class

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Meeting implements Serializable {
@XmlAttribute
private int option;
private String time;
private String date;
@XmlElement(name = "responses")
private ArrayList<Response> responses = new ArrayList<Response>();
```

basically the data from poll is getting marshalled in fine (i have checked this) but once it hits meetings it makes the list with one entry that is empty am i missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be missing a **Meetings** class (corresponding to `<meetings>` )wrapping the **Meeting** instances (corresponding to `<meeting>`).

If you generated the JAXB using a tool like XJC this wouldn't have happened, so it's not clear how you ended up in this situation (maybe you were trying to customize something).   But maybe this helps in any case.

Comment: thank you ill have a look into XJC it may be easier to get it up and runnning :)